# MVC @Url.Action not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
<div class="col-xs-6 text-right margin-top-x5">
     <div class="adduser pointer" data-url="@Url.Action("Register","Account")"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-user"></span>&nbsp;Add New User</div>
</div>
```

On FireBug i can see but it not going to that action.

```
<div class="adduser pointer" data-url="/Account/Register">
```

Comment: I hope you're not trying to use a `div` as an `a` element. What are you expecting it will happen? Are trying to navigate to that URL? Are you trying to load a partial view inside the `div`?

Comment: Your `Url.Action()` is fine. The problem is in the way you're using it. Ask yourself why is it in `data-url` and not in `<a href="...">`

Comment: <div class="adduser pointer"> <a href="@Url.Action("Register")"></a><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-user"></span>&nbsp;Add New User</div>   - even this not working

Comment: But i am able to hit that action when i type the Url - http://localhost:12734/Account/register

Comment: Finally this worked - <div class="adduser pointer"> <a href="@Url.Action("Register")"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-user"></span>&nbsp;Add New User</a></div>

Answer (score 1):

If you want a `div` to be clickable, you have to give it some code to do something when the user clicks it.

```
$(function() {
    $("[data-url]").click(function() {
        location.href = $(this).data("url");
    });
}
```

Alternatively, just use an anchor:

```
 <a class="adduser pointer" href="@Url.Action("Register","Account")">
    <span class="glyphicons glyphicons-user"></span>&nbsp;Add New User</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

`@Url.Action("Register","Account")` is supposed to only print out the URL of the respective action at the specific place.

What you need instead is `@Html.Action`. Read more about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703423(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: It will be probably useful to mention that `@Html.Action` should not be used inside a `data-` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Are you possibly attempting to use an anchor?

```
<div class="col-xs-6 text-right margin-top-x5">
    <a class="adduser pointer" href="@Url.Action("Register","Account")">
<span class="glyphicons glyphicons-user"></span>&nbsp;Add New User</div>
```

Or you could use a `Html.ActionLink`

```
<div class="col-xs-6 text-right margin-top-x5"> 
<span class="glyphicons glyphicons-user" />
@Html.ActionLink("Add New User", "Register", "Account", null, new { @class = "adduser pointer" })
```