# Url.Action link doesn't work when I apply a bootstrap class to it

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

Hi I'm using a bootstrap template but I don't understand why my link doesn't work.

The link **doesn't** work styling of button is what I want.

```
<li>
    <a href="@Url.Action("Login", "Account")" class="btn btn-link-2 scroll-link"><span>Sign In</span></a>
</li>
```

Generated html:

```
<li><a href="/Account/Login" class="btn btn-link-2 scroll-link"><span>Sign In</span></a></li>
```

The link **does** work but the styling of button isn't what I want.

```
<li>
    <a href="@Url.Action("Login", "Account")"><span>Sign In</span></a>
</li>
```

Generated html:

```
<li><a href="/Account/Login"><span>Sign In</span></a></li>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is not working? Both produce an identical `href` attribute. The first one should work fine

Comment: It doesn't direct me to the action controller when I apply the class to it... thats the part I don't understand. I'm not sure if it's because of the bootstrap  class.

Comment: It should not have anything to do with the class names. Edit your question to show the actual html that these are generating.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31155303/mvc-url-action-not-working

Comment: Stephen I don't understand what you mean by "show the actual html that these are generating" Isn't that what I posted?

Comment: No, you have posted your code. Run the app, right click and 'View Source' and copy the html. But I cant see its an issue anyway - both should be producing `<a href="/Account/Login" ....` (but just to be sure, include it)

Comment: They're exactly the same links - is it something to do with the page that you're on at the time? Do have have areas in your project?

Comment: Your link may overlap with other html elements when applying style on it

Comment: Thanks Gene. I removed the scroll-link class and it resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `scroll-link` class fixed the problem.